# Is there any way to load the FB javascript sdk in a sandboxed iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to load the `Facebook Javascript SDK` in a sandboxed iframe. Now even if I load the SDK in my iframe page, the FB object is created in the parent window. I want the FB object in the iframe scope. I want to isolate the FB javascript SDK from the parent window. Is it possible?

Comment: Really? That sounds like a recipe for CSRF if that’s possible.

Comment: Unsure if there is an official way to do that, but you could always put your iframe in a different domain so the same origin policy would apply, and your iframe wouldn't be able to communicate with the parent using Javascript.

Comment: @StevenVondruska With your solution i have this error: 

_Blocked a frame with origin "..main page origin.." from accessing a frame with origin "..iframe origin..". Protocols, domains, and ports must match._ 

THe sdk try to add FB object to the parent, but for same origin policy it cannot.

Comment: @MartinBean The goal is try to use FB api in a sanboxed scope (iframe), and communicate with the parent via window messages.